# React dev server does not proxy form submissions

Tags: reactjs, forms, webpack-dev-server

I created a react app using create-react-app and my proxy works fine when sending requests with axios.

What I want to do it a "normal" form submission (no onsubmit function with axios). I want to do this because my Node.js server will then redirect me (axios won't send the user/browser to the redirect and will just follow it through requests, which I do not want)

When my form is submitted it just goes to my dev server `localhost:3000/login` instead of my node server `localhost:8080/login` and I believe this is because

> The development server will only attempt to send requests without text/html in its Accept header to the proxy.

[source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development)

And I see the request from my form submission does indeed have that header, which is probably why its ignoring it.

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

Is there a way to do a "normal" form submission that is proxied to my node server instead of the dev server?

I think this would work in production since its all running on the same server there, so I am thinking why would it work in production, but not be a possibility in development?

Here is what my form looks like

```
render() {
    return <div>
        <Form action='/login' className="some-class">
            <Button type="submit" className="some-class">
                Log In
            </Button>
        </Form>
    </div>
}
```

And here is what my proxy config looks like in package.json

```
"proxy": "https://localhost:8080/"
```

Comment: I am running into this issue as well, which unfortunately I still haven't managed to figure it out lol. But the documentation did say that `text/html` cannot be in the request header for the proxy to work though. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're moving into front-end routing, I'd recommend integrating `react-router` (I prefer v3.0.4 over v4.x) for handling front-end routing only and `express` (or whatever you're using) for handling back-end API requests only.

The following example is for **routing demonstration purposes only** and shouldn't be used as is.

First, set up a proxy in the client's `package.json` (the main advantage of this is to avoid using `CORS`):

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080"
  }
}
```

My client `routes` would be setup so that `App` always stays mounted and acts like a pass-through for `children` routes:

**client/src/routes/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import App from '../components/App';
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
);
```

In my `App.js`, I could use an `isAuthenticated` state check:

**client/src/components/App.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

export default class App extends Component {
    state = { isAuthenticated: false };

    componentDidMount = () => !this.state.isAuthenticated && browserHistory.push('/')

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => !this.state.isAuthenticated && browserHistory.push('/')

    authenticated = () => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true }, () => browserHistory.push('/dashboard'))

    render = () => (
       !this.state.isAuthenticated
          ? <LoginForm authenticated={this.authenticated} />
          : <Fragment>
             {this.props.children}
            </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Then, in the `LoginForm` component, I could set `isAuthenticated` to true via `this.props.authenticated` upon a successful `AJAX` request, and then redirect to `dashboard`:

**client/src/components/LoginForm.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = {
    login: "",
    password: ""
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { login, password } = this.state;
    if (!login || !password ) return;

    axios.post('/api/login', { login, password })
      .then(() => this.props.authenticated())
      .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()))
  }

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="some-class">
      <input 
        name="login"
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.login} 
        placeholder="Username" 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <input 
        name="password"
        type="password" 
        value={this.state.password} 
        placeholder="Password" 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <button type="submit" className="some-class">
        Log In
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Then the express server `routes` would look for the `POST` request:

**server/routes/auth.js**

```
const { login } = require('../controllers/auth.js');

app.post('/login', login);
```

Then, I could authenticate the user via `passport` in my express controller (if the user fails to be auth'd, then it'll be caught in the AJAX `.catch()` inside `handleSubmit`):

**server/controllers/auth.js**

```
exports.login = (req, res, done) => passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, user) => {
                  if (err || !user) { res.status(404).json({ err: "Authentication failed." }); done(); }

                  res.status(201).send(null);
                })(req, res, done)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for this answer, I looked into routing with react, but it seems like overkill for what I want. I only need 1 form submission to act normal and nothing else. Instead, I had the server send back a 204 with a location header and had the browser do the redirect. It woulda been nice to know a way to get the server to do the redirect instead (without adding in routing).

Answer (score 0):

To proxy non AJAX calls through react, you will need to install `http-proxy-middleware` and configure proxy manually.

First install `http-proxy-middleware`  in your react app

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
```

Then create `src/setupProxy.js` file with below configuration

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8080',
      secure: false,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Now simply start the application and you will see that non AJAX calls (form submissions, php, html document etc) are also being proxied correctly.

**Note:** Remove the proxy configuration from `package.json` file before configuring it manually with `http-proxy-middleware` otherwise the proxy won't work correctly if defined at both the places